# Is there a way to use redigo with data text file as well as redis-cli pipeline?

Tags: go, redis

I use Redis bulk insert feature with pipeline.

I have `data.txt` file.

```
FLUSHDB
HSET 02-00-101 date "2021-03-15"
HSET 02-00-102 date "2021-03-15"
HSET 02-00-103 date "2021-03-15"
HSET 02-00-104 date "2021-03-15"
HSET 02-00-105 date "2021-03-15"
```

then insert the data to Redis DB like below.

```
cat data.txt | redis-cli --pipe
```

I'd like to use [redigo](https://github.com/gomodule/redigo) in Golang and reuse the `data.txt` file.

Is there a way to use redigo with the data text file as well as redis-cli pipeline above?

Comment: redigo supports pipelines. You can read the file line-by-line and send in the pipeline

Comment: Yes. I understand I can use the pipelining feature of Redigo but I'd like to use the text file directly. I don't know if I eventually need to move the file's data to Golang's struct as binary.